# How to get the base address of a DLL from a process using ctypes?

Tags: python, ctypes

I need to know the address of the DLL connected to the process. In pymem I would do this:

```
base_address = pymem.process.module_from_name(process.process_handle, "name.dll").lpBaseOfDll
```

Comment: pymem is written using ctypes so you could look at the source for that https://github.com/srounet/Pymem/blob/master/pymem/process.py - why do you need this? why do you need to use ctypes directly?